# why do I have to use required parametres?

Tags: plugin-development, author, parameter

Why, when I want to use

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'foo', 10, 3 );
function foo ( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ) {}
```

I have to use 3 required parametres? 
Why cant I do this:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'foo' );
function foo ( $author_id ) {}
```

If you can, please give me some literature about this.

PS beginner in WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to specify number of arguments, in which case it will default to one.

Essentially this argument gives you control on how many arguments hook will pass to function, which matters in few too many situations to come up with generic explanation.

In a nutshell if hook can pass N arguments, your options are:

- pass 1 argument (default)
- pass <=N arguments by specifying number
- do not pass any arguments by specifying 0 (rare, but highly useful at times)

Note that you cannot change order of arguments passed, if you need Nth you will need to pass as many and then ignore unwanted ones in your function (which only makes sense in few hooks, because first argument tends to be meaningful one, rarely second).

Answer (score 1):

If you require only the first argument to fulfil your job then it is not necessary to specify the number of arguments. The number of arguments need to be specified if the function you are writing might need the extra information (arguments).

The first argument is actually what you should be returning back in your function. The other arguments act as helpers to get the desired output.

Comment: and if I need only second argument?

Comment: Then you could try this maybe
`add_filter( 'author_link', 'foo', 10, 2 ); function foo ( $link, $author_id ) {}`
But you will have to use the first argument also. Have not tested if the above thing would work. It should work though.

Comment: Yes, it works with two args. Thanks.
But where can I find info about this requirements?